Proof of Lemma for Mean value theorem for any Norm
I need help with this result:
Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\phi: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, differentiable functions. If $|f'(t)| \leq \phi'(t)$ and $\phi'(t) > 0$ for all $t\in [a,b]$, then $|f(b) - f(a) | \leq \phi(b) - \phi(a)$.
My attempt:
I defined $X = \left\{ t\in [a,b] \: : \: |f(t) - f(a) | \leq \phi(t) - \phi(a) \right\}$. The set $X$ is bounded $X\subset [a,b]$; and is closed, because it is the pre-image $g^{-1}([0, \infty))$ of the continuous function $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(t) = [\phi(t) - \phi(a)] - |f(t) - f(a)|$. Also, $X$ is not empty, because $a\in X$.
Defining $s = \sup X \in X$. If  $s = b$, we are done, because  $s = b \in X \implies | f(b) - f(a) | \leq \phi(b) - \phi(a)$. Assuming $s\neq b \implies s<b$.
If $s<t<b$,  we must have $|f(t) - f(s)| > \phi(t) - \phi(s)$, because if $|f(t) - f(s)| \leq \phi(t) - \phi(s)$, then $|f(t) - f(a) | \leq |f(t) - f(s) | + |f(s) - f(a) | \leq \phi(t) - \phi(a) \implies t\in X$ (contradiction). Therefore
$$ |f'(s)| = \lim_{t\to s} \dfrac{|f(t) - f(s)|}{|t-s|} = \lim_{t\to s^+} \dfrac{|f(t) -f(s)|}{t-s} \geq \lim_{t\to s^+} \dfrac{\phi(t) -\phi(s)}{t-s} = \phi'(s)$$
From $|f'(s) | \leq \phi'(s)$, we get $|f'(s)| = \phi'(s)$.
I couldn't proceed from here. I tried looking at what happens if you approach $s$ from the left side, but couldn't get something useful. Also I didn't use the fact that $\phi'(t) >0$ for all $t\in [a,b]$.

I think it's easier to use $f(b) - f(a) = \int_{a}^{b}f'(t),dt$ and then justify $|\int_{a}^{b}f'(t),dt| \leq \int_{a}^{b}|f'(t)|,dt$

I don't know if f' is integrable. That's the problem with this approach.
